# Cannot close the media player of LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

I added a sound from the gallery and now I cannot close the integrated media player. I guess it's a bug but how can I close it anyway? The small window doesnt have window decorators.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Tools menu, and click Gallery Player. This toggles the player visibility.

I don't know why it's undecorated for you. Might be a Unity/Compiz quirk (I only use Compiz and it's decorated). You should file a bug.

Answer (score 2):

On Libre Office 3.6.3.2 I finally figured out you can look for the double headed arrow at edge of media player and grab it, pull to left edge of work space.

A marker grip appears so you can find and open it in the future - BUT IT IS NO LONGER taking 1/3 of the display area and is out of the way!  This is acceptable!  Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a known bug, so you are not alone. The above solution did not work for me. Here is what did.

**To close the Media Player of Libre Office Writer:**

1. On the bottom area of the Media Player pane click and hold on a part of the gray area where there are no buttons.
2. Drag the pane to the middle of the main document window.
3. The pane now becomes a floating window.
4. Click on the red "x" to close the window.

To transform the floating window back into a pane, drag it back to any side of the main document window.

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug? That would make this answer much more useful!